# How to add external variables to a SPARQL query?

Tags: python, sparql, turtle-rdf, knowledge-graph, sparqlwrapper

I have the following codes:

```
name = [str(s) for s,  in graph.query('''
    SELECT ?lbl 
    WHERE {
        <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q59692464> <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657> ?obj .
        ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }
    ''')]
```

I want to pass the two values`<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q59692464>`and `<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657>` as variables `?mov` and `?rel`.

I tried to use %s but got an error:

```
name = [str(s) for s,  in graph.query('''
    SELECT ?lbl 
    WHERE {
        <'%s'> <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657> ?obj .
        ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }
    '''%mov)]
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'SPARQLResult' and 'str'
```

What I want is something like this:

```
name = [str(s) for s,  in graph.query('''
    SELECT ?lbl 
    WHERE {
        ?mov ?rel ?obj .
        ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }
    ''')]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: 1.) your code looks more like rdflib and not sparqlwrapper, thus, if you didn't load anything from Wikidata into the `graph`, it will be empty for obvious reasons. So if you didn't load some Wikidata fragment into your rdflib graph, then you should follow the documentation of sparqlwrapper instead: https://sparqlwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html

Comment: 2) why do you put `%s` in to single quotes? The whole multiline string IS already a string, inlining string variables just needs an `%s`

Comment: 3) do you really want all the labels? If not, put a `FILTER` in your SPARQL query

Comment: `from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

mov = 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q59692464'

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

sparql.setQuery('''
    SELECT ?lbl 
    WHERE {
        <%s> <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657> ?obj .
        ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
        FILTER(lang(?lbl) = "en")
    }
    ''' % mov)

try:
    ret = sparql.queryAndConvert()

    for r in ret["results"]["bindings"]:
        print(r['lbl']['value'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `rdflib`, you can do something like this:

```
mov = rdflib.URIRef("http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q59692464")
rel = rdflib.URIRef("http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657")

name = [str(s) for s, in graph.query('''
SELECT ?lbl 
WHERE {
  ?mov ?rel ?obj .
  ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
}
''', initBindings={'mov': mov, 'rel': rel})]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using double curly braces and the .format method. See:

```
name = [str(s) for s in graph.query('''
    SELECT ?lbl 
    WHERE {{
        {} {} ?obj .
        ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }}
    '''.format("<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q59692464>", "<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657>"))]
```

I would probably break this up and format the query as a string, and then call `graph.query()`:

```
skeleton_query = '''
    SELECT ?lbl 
    WHERE {{
        {} {} ?obj .
        ?obj rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }}
    '''

formatted_query = skeleton_query.format("<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q59692464>", "<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1657>")

result = graph.query(formatted_query)
```